# jQuery VF window popup issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

I want to open a popup window using jQuery after clicking on "more" button..

jQuery more/less link in pageblock table

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>jQuery Add More/Less link to Text</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        var showChar = 120,
        showtxt = "more",
        hidetxt = "less";
        $('.sfdc_richtext').each(function ()
        {
            var content = $(this).text();
            if (content.length > showChar)
            {
                var con = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var hcon = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
                var txt = con + '<span class="dots">...</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + hcon + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="moretxt">' + showtxt + '</a></span>';
                $(this).html(txt);
            }
        });

        $(".moretxt").click(function ()
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass("sfdc_richtext"))
            {
                $(this).removeClass("sfdc_richtext");
                $(this).text(showtxt);
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).addClass("sfdc_richtext");
                $(this).text(hidetxt);
            }

            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using this jQuery code I am able to show the more/less link in which characters are more than 120. Now I want to open a VF window pop when anyone clicks on that more link. I am new to jQuery please help. I also need to pass an id to that VF page window popup when anyone clicks on more link.

[image]

above is the page block table and more link in image.

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!salesFaqList}" var="faq" id="pbTable" rendered="{!showData}">

                  <apex:column value="{!faq.FAQ_Categories__c}" width="190px" style="height:50px"/>

      <apex:column value="{!faq.Answer__c}" /> 
 </apex:pageBlockTable >
```

Answer is the last field in page block table. I want to open a VF pop up window on click of that link and also pass ID in URL of that page.

Comment: In Salesforce, you'll want to use [jQuery's no conflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). `var j = jQuery.noConflict();` Then replace `$` with `j`.

Comment: Hi More/Less link are working fine..I want to open a window pop on more link..I dont know how to do that..??Can you help

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand well your question.. but this link could to help you, about how to do a popup when you click it in a link.

https://vibanterence-apexvisualforce.blogspot.com.es/2014/07/visualforce-jquery-ui-dialog-displaying.html?showComment=1462893676752#c7480854185459541626

If you need more help, tell me. I did this tutorial. ;) And it worked! I had to use this jquerys...

```
  <apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css"/>
```